# How to send POST request to secure Laravel API route from Postman

Tags: laravel, authorization, postman

I am having problems in submitting POST request to secured Laravel API routes via Postman. My GET requests work fine, but my POST cant go through the security even though I have provided an api token.
So my question is: **How properly to send POST request to secured Laravel API routes from Postman?**

Answer (score 0):

**Add this is the request header.**

```
[enter image description here][1]accept: application/json
content-type: application/json
authorization: "your_token"
```

Answer (score -1):

**Found the solution:**

Set your Authorization to API Key:

[image: Screenshot]

Next, in headers section you need to add X-Requested-With field:

[image: Screenshot 2]